# How to test restful JSON create entity action?

Tags: symfony, testing, functional-testing, symfony-2.3

I'm trying to test my create action. It simply gets the data passed by json content (the application uses backbonejs) and validates it againts the correspondent form type. The form is still indicating error "csrf token invalid". The test environment uses the MockFileSessionStorage to generate the csrf token. I tried to generated the token and then sending the session cookie together with the request, but it did not worked.

Bellow is the testing class.

```
<?php
namespace Company\ServiceBundle\Tests\Controller;


use Liip\FunctionalTestBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client;
use Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Cookie;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Csrf\CsrfProvider\CsrfProviderInterface;

class EntidadeControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testCreate()
    {

        $dados = array(
            'nome' => 'Entidade TESTE 01',
            'ativo' => 0,
            '_token' => $this->csrfDefaultToken
        );

        $crawler = $this->client->request(
            'POST',
            '/admin/entidades',
            array(),
            array(),
            array(
               'CONTENT_TYPE'          => 'application/json',
               'HTTP_X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest'
            ),
            json_encode(array('cartorio_servico_entidade'=>$dados))
        );

        $this->assertEquals(201, $this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
    }

    /** @var Client $client */
    protected $client;
    /** @var CsrfProviderInterface $csrfProvider */
    protected $csrfProvider;

    /** @var string $csrfDefaultToken */
    protected $csrfDefaultToken;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->csrfProvider = $this->getContainer()->get('form.csrf_provider');
        $this->csrfDefaultToken = $this->csrfProvider->generateCsrfToken('unknown');

        $this->client = static::createClient(
            array(),
            array('PHP_AUTH_USER' => 'admin', 'PHP_AUTH_PW' => '123456')
        );

        // session cookie - necessario para nao dar problema com o CSRF token
        $cookie = new Cookie('PHPSESSID', $this->getContainer()->get('session')->getId(), time() + 3600 * 24 * 7, '/', null, false, false);
        $this->client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);

        $fixtures = array(
            'Company\ServiceBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadUserData'
        );
        $this->loadFixtures($fixtures);
    }
}
```

Bellow is the action code. It's really just a simple validate the form data and go.

```
/**
 * Create new resource or just display the form.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $config = $this->getConfiguration();

    $resource = $this->createNew();
    $form = $this->getForm($resource);

    if ($request->isMethod('POST') && $form->bind($request)->isValid()) {

        /** @var ResourceEvent $event */
        $event = $this->create($resource);

        if (!$event->isStopped()) {
            return new Response(json_encode('criado'), 201, array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));
        }
    }

    if ($config->isApiRequest()) {
        return $this->handleView($this->view($form));
    }

    return new Response(json_encode('nao criado'), 404, array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));
}
```

Comment: tried to disable the csrf validation for the test, or is it necessary to be enabled ?

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#csrf-protection

Comment: Yeah, I did forget about disabling it only for the test environment! It works well once disabled. Thanks, nixoschu!

Answer (score 0):

A way to get started is to add this into your forms type class:

```
    // TODO: remove this once we have auth working.
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'csrf_protection'   => false,
    ));
```

Obviously security needs to be considered, but this may help newbies get off the ground.